# Saving custom form data

Tags: custom-field

These are steps I took when creating my custom form.

1. Added my html form code directly to a page (all working fine)
2. Added some code to creat some dependent dropdown list using Header, Footer plugin (all working fine)

My question is, how do I save the form data to the custom table I created in my wordpress db?

Comment: you can create your table and use `$wpdb` to save the data to db.

Comment: Where would I place the code?

Comment: custom template would be preferable.

Comment: If I use a custom page template will it be overwritten if the theme is updated?

Comment: You should use child theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could use woody code snippets

https://woodysnippet.com/getting-started-with-woody-ad-snippets/

to add PHP code to your page that saves data in your table.